# how to use same module using different routes in angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, menu

I am working on a angular application, where we have multiple menus(A,B,C,D,E) which uses same module.
menus A,C and E uses same component/module.
my requirement is when i am on A, and if i click C on menu same component should be loaded, with different data. I am using navigateRoot function of NavController from '@ionic/angular' for navigation whenever a menu item is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make 2 routes, both of which you load the same component.
For example:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'edit/:id', component: EditCustomerComponent },
    { path: 'add', component: EditCustomerComponent },
];
```